# Verify that a CSV file contains a backup job for every prod job

Tags: bash, csv

This is a list of jobs in autosys. What I have to do is make sure that every job in PROD has a accompanying job in BACKUP.

The jobs are formatted as `CAPSER_JOB_01_PP`. I read the list into a while loop, not sure if I should take an `-r`.

I take off the last two characters of the job name, and then grep twice for each area, if both are successful it prints a `yes` at beginning of line, otherwise it is a `no`.

Frankly I can't find matching documentation for the `${job%??}`. I don't know what the two question marks stand for.

I tried using `grep -q` but it did not work. the `> 2>&1 /dev/null` did not work either, I had to reverse it to `> /dev/null` the redirect `2>&1` (as shown). The script works, it is just a clunky way of getting it done. There has to be a better way.

```
#!/bin/bash
#bash, version 3.2.25


IFS=,

while read area job machine script
do
if grep  ${job%??} /home/first_spreadsheet.txt | grep BACKUP >/dev/null 2>&1 && grep  ${job%??} /home/first_spreadsheet.txt | grep PROD  >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
echo " YES $area $job $machine $script "
else
echo " NO $area $job $machine $script "
fi
sleep 1
done < /home/first_spreadsheet.txt
```

---

```
cat /home/first_spreadsheet.txt
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_01_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '/usr/bin/run.sh'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_01_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '/usr/bin/run.sh'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_02_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script02'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_02_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script02'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_03_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script03'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_03_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script03'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_04_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script04'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_04_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script04'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_05_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script05'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_06_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script06'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_07_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script07'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_07_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script07'
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review.  Your "Frankly..." line makes it sound like you have questions that would be better for other sites like StackOverflow.  Are you ready for a code review?

Comment: Stackoverflow sent me here - the script works, I just don't know. There has to be a better way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966603/issues-in-a-bash-loop-that-processes-a-large-delimited-file seems to be the other question.

Answer (score 1):

> I take off the last two characters of the job name, and then grep twice for each area, if both are successful it prints a yes at beginning of line, otherwise it is a no.
>
> Frankly I can't find matching documentation for the `${job%??}`. I don't know what the two question marks stand for.

`${job%??}` takes the last two characters off the value of `$job`.
The `${parameter%word}` syntax is explained in `man bash` in the **Parameter Expansion** section.
The valid patterns in `word` are shell glob patterns.
A `?` in shell glob patterns means any single character.
So two `?` mean any two characters.

> I tried using `grep -q` but it did not work.

Saying "it did not work" always invites the question "what happened?".
I'd recommend to eliminate the phrase "it did not work" from your vocabulary.
I guess one of two things happened:

- The command gave an error, perhaps `grep: invalid option -- 'q'`

  - This can happen if the implementation of `grep` in your system does not have such option.
- The command did not give an error, but output was not suppressed.

  - This should be impossible, so I suspect a mistake on your part. If we had the exact command you executed, and the input and output, we could probably explain the mistake.

> the `> 2>&1 /dev/null` did not work either, I had to reverse it to `> /dev/null` the redirect `2>&1` (as shown).

It's a bit difficult to understand this sentence.
In any case, `> 2>&1 /dev/null` is invalid syntax.
Perhaps you meant that instead of `2>&1 >/dev/null` you had to write `>/dev/null 2>&1` to get the desired effect.
Yes the meaning of these two ways are different.
The effect of `2>&1 >/dev/null` is that `stderr` will be written to `stdout` and the original `stdout` will be discarded.
The effect of `>/dev/null 2>&1` is that both `stdout` and `stderr` will be discarded.
This works by thinking of pointer assignments,
I can go into more detail if needed.

> The script works, it is just a clunky way of getting it done. There has to be a better way.

A couple of things can be improved:

- If the file `/home/first_spreadsheet.txt` exists, then `grep` should not write anything to `stderr`, so no need to redirect that
- It would be better to store repeatedly used values like `${job%??}` and `/home/first_spreadsheet.txt` in helper variables
- It's good limit the scope of changing the value of `IFS` to avoid unintended effects later in the script. You can do that by prefixing the command that needs it, in this example `read`
- To avoid redirecting the output of individual `grep` commands, you could group them together and redirect the output of the grouping

Putting the above together (and then some),
you could write a bit simpler like this:

```
path=/home/first_spreadsheet.txt
while IFS=, read area job machine script
do
    job0=${job%??}
    if { grep $job0 "$path" | grep BACKUP && grep $job0 "$path" | grep PROD; } >/dev/null; then
        printf " YES "
    else
        printf " NO "
    fi
    echo "$area $job $machine $script"
done < "$path"
```

Comment: `grep $job0 "$path" | grep BACKUP` can be combined into `grep "^BACKUP.*$job0" "$path"`